# Enabling PEP on ejabberd server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, node-xmpp

I'm creating a chat app using the Electron Framework and node-xmpp module for XMPP communication.

I have managed to do almost everything except making Personal Eventing Protocol to work. Specifically sending a new nickname to the roster.

When I send the PEP stanza

```
<iq from='test@localhost' type='set' id='pub1'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <publish node='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>
      <item>
        <nick xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>I am a test user</nick>
      </item>
    </publish>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

I get a response IQ stanza:

```
<iq from="test@localhost" type="result" to="test@localhost/testapp" id="pub1">
  <pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
    <publish node="http://jabber.org/protocol/nick">
      <item id="5D4E0BB8EB3C6"/>
    </publish>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

Now, according to [XEP-172 example  6](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0172.html#message) I should get a Message with the nickname that is also sent to all my contacts. It should look like this:

```
<message from='test@localhost' to='otheruser@localhost' type='headline' id='foo'>
  <event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'>
    <items node='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>
      <item>
        <nick xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>I am a test user</nick>
      </item>
    </items>
  </event>
  <addresses xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/address'>
    <address type='replyto' jid='test@localhost/chatapp'/>
  </addresses>
</message>
```

The thing is I'm not getting any message to other contacts in the user's roster. Not even to myself.

Is there any step I'm missing to enable PEP on a ejabberd server? Any extra stanza or information I should include?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive other users' nickname events you should include `http://jabber.org/protocol/nick+notify` string into your [Entity Capabilities](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html) list.

See [Filtered notifications](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#filtered-notifications) for detailed description.